# Android INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE for app that has no previous versions on the device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to install an app from Android Studio on an Android device.
I am constantly getting `INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` error, even though:

- App does not exist on the device
- I've changed the package and application to be sure that there is no residue of any previous version
- I've invalidated the cache and restarted android studio
- I've done clean and rebuild
- I've raised the version code to a big number that I am sure has never been installed on a device.

Nothing has helped.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

When I run `adb logcat | grep -i version`  I can see this:

```
PackageManager: Downgrade detected: Update version code 14 is older than the current 28
```

But the version code in `build.grade` is **31**.

Comment: What is your install command? Try the following, by using the downgrade flag : ```adb install -r -d <link to apk>```. Do this to prove that your install works, then check if there is anything with a similar name on the phone that has a version number higher than your installation. Have you tried implementing your app on another android device or emulator ?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried more installing commands. In the meantime, I've found the reason why this happens, which is another problem I don't understand why happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571423/built-apk-has-wrong-metadata-packagename-is-android-instead-of-my-real-packag